# How to keep rows that have non-zero entries for different column names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = structure(list(climate = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), pricestability = c(3, 
0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 4, 0, 1, 0), macro = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 3, 
0, 2), `pension and savings` = c(2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 10, 8, 1, 0, 
0), macro = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), macro = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1), macro = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), macro = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0), quality = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `pension and savings` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0), `fiscal policy` = c(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), macro = c(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")


       climate pricestability macro pension and savings macro macro macro macro quality
1        0              3     0                   2     0     0     0     2       0
2        0              0     0                   0     0     1     2     0       0
3        0              0     0                   1     0     0     1     0       0
4        0              3     0                   0     0     0     0     0       0
5        0              0     0                   0     0     0     0     0       0
6        0              2     0                  10     0     0     0     0       0
7        0              4    14                   8     0     2     0     0       0
8        0              0     3                   1     0     0     0     2       0
9        0              1     0                   0     0     0     0     0       0
10       0              0     2                   0     0     1     0     0       0
        pension and savings fiscal policy macro
1                    0             0     0
2                    0             0     0
3                    0             0     0
4                    0             2     2
5                    0             0     0
6                    2             0     0
7                    2             0     0
8                    0             0     0
9                    0             0     0
10                   0             0     1
```

I want to know which row contains an entry that is different from 0 but only for different column names. Let me take the first and second row of the dataframe above as an example:

```
# this is the first row

     climate pricestability macro pension and savings    macro macro macro macro quality
        0              3         0                   2     0     0     0     2       0

# this row should be signalled since there are 3 non-zero entries whoe column names differ from each other

# this is the second row:

  climate pricestability macro pension and savings    macro macro macro macro   quality
     0              0        0           0              0     1     2     0       0

# this row should not be signalled because there two non-zero entri BUT the column names are the same
```

Is there anyone who can help me with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `any` and `anyDuplicated`.

```
apply(df != 0, 1, function(x) any(x) & !anyDuplicated(names(x)[x]))
#    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10 
# TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```